# Sending request direct from PHP works but calling the PHP from AJAX to send request doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send an ajax call to a PHP file, in which I have Javascript code to send data to SurveyJS (https://surveyjs.io/).

Calling ajaxOriginator.html using "localhost/testSurvey/ajaxOriginator.html" successfully calls receiver.php and the JavaScript in receiver.php runs but does not send out the request to SurveyJS.

If I call receiver.php directly using "localhost/testSurvey/receiver.php", it successfully sends out the request to SurveyJS and I can see the data received.

Here is ajaxOriginator.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Ajax originator</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.get('receiver.php', { "name": "Julia", "car": "Kia" });
</script>

</head>
```

This is receiver.php

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["name"];
$car = $_GET["car"];
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://surveyjs.azureedge.net/1.0.16/survey.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var json = {};

window.survey = new Survey.Model(json);

//To test if ajax call works and it does
var values = ["<?php echo $name; ?>", "<?php echo $car; ?>"];

//To send data directly to SurveyJS
values = ["John", "somecar"];

var deepSurveyCopy = $.extend(true, {}, survey);
console.log(deepSurveyCopy);
deepSurveyCopy.data.name = values[0];   
deepSurveyCopy.data.car = values[1];    
deepSurveyCopy.sendResult(my access key to surveyJS);
</script>

<?php
echo "Welcome ". $name. "<br />";
echo "You want ". $car;
?>
```

Here are screenshots from Chrome and SurveyJS:
[image: AjaxOriginator.html to receiver.php]
[image: Calling receiver.php directly]
[image: Data received from calling receiver.php directly]

I am not very well-versed in PHP and would appreciate any help in understanding how all these work (and not work) together.

Basically ajaxOriginator.html is to simulate a plugin which is going to send data out to receiver.php, in which I am trying to wrap the data received in a format SurveyJS accepts and resend to SurveyJS.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you request HTML from the server using `$.get()`, the browser will load the document but not run the JavaScript code inside. It looks like you expect PHP and JS to run sort of simultaneously, but that's not how it works. All PHP code is executed on the server, the result is sent to the browser. *If* the page is visited the usual way (i.e. via address bar / link), then the JS code runs, in the browser. I guess what you want to do is look at SurveyJS's Web API and [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), PHP's equivalent of `$.get()`.

Comment: Tks for the answer. I cannot find any API by SurveyJS that allows me to change the survey results programmatically. Is it not possible to use $.get() to make the PHP code run JS somehow? Maybe not in the same file but trigger the JS?

Comment: PHP cannot run JS, only the browser's JS engine can run JS. If you want JS code to run in the browser, just put it in a function and call it.